# How select a variable range to paste in VBA when there are blank cells in between

Tags: excel, vba, cell, vba6

[image: PLease find the attcahed screenshot of my excel sheet]

I want to paste a formula of VLOOKUP in my whole column but the last cell changes everyday. How to select the variable last cell of Column "S" according to the last cell in column "A".

```
Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

'
Range("S2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
Range("S2:S38").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Copy
Range("S2").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Comment: `Dim lastRow As Long`, `lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`,  `With Range("S2:S" & lastRow)`, `.Value = .Value`, `End With`.

Comment: If you put your data into an [Excel table](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c) then  your formula will automatically fill down as you add new data.  No VBA required.